# Comparing two lists and removing elements which don't meet the criterion in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `J_new` and `C`. For every `True` element of `C`, I want to remove the corresponding element in `J_new`. For instance, since `C[0]=True`, I want to remove `J_new[0]=1`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
J_new = [1, 9, 15]
C=[True, True, False]

for i in range(0,len(C)): 
    if(C[i]=='True'):
        C[i]=[]
        J_new=J_new[C[i]]
print(J_new)
```

The current output is

```
[1, 9, 15]
```

The expected output is

```
[15]
```

Comment: The string `'True'` is not the same as the Boolean value `True`.  Just say `if C[i]:`.  There is no need to modify `C` at all.  What you need to do is create a new list with the elements you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing parallel lists, always think "[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)"!

```
>>> J_new = [1, 9, 15]
>>> C = [True, True, False]
>>> 
>>> [j for j, c in zip(J_new, C) if not c]
[15]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code for get required output:

```
J_new = [1, 9, 15]
C = [True, True, False]

J_new = [J_new[i] for i in range(len(C)) if not C[i]]

print(J_new)
```

Result:

```
[15]
```